# sec:authorize does not work on thymeleaf with hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN) or other

Tags: spring, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to authorize access to some buttons to some specific lvl of authority. I have seen other questions, but all solutions that i saw did not work.

i have doing:

```
        <div class="col-sm-2" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <b>Approve Plan </b></button></a> 
        </div>
```

i have also tested.

```
sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')"
sec:authorize="hasRole('APPROVER')"
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"
```

The button is always shown independent of the user authority thought it should be visible only to approver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have below dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-thymeleaf)

Comment: i did not have it but it did not fix the problem. All cases do the same

Comment: which version of spring do you use? based on that you can change thymeleaf extra version.

Comment: i have placed 
org.springframework.boot version:2.0.0.RELEASEthymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 version 2.1.2

Comment: some extra clean project and maven update project except the automated one was needed